# subsequent macro detection

Tags: best-practices

I would like to detect subsequent macros, in order to insert superscript numbers. If two macros follow each other, a comma should be inserted in between.

The minimal example (stripped of the useful stuff to make it minimal):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\providecommand*{\multiplefootnotemarker}{3sp}

\NewDocumentCommand \marker { } {%
\kern-\multiplefootnotemarker%
\kern\multiplefootnotemarker\relax%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \checker { } {%
\ifdim\lastkern=\multiplefootnotemarker\relax%
      \textsuperscript{,}%
\fi%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \fullcite { m } {%
#1%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \margincite { m } {%
\sidenote{\fullcite{#1}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \sidenote { m } {%
\sidenotemark%
\sidenotetext{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \sidenotemark { } {%
\checker%
\textsuperscript{1}%
\marker%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { m } {%
\marginpar{#1}%
\marker
}

\begin{document}
1 Text\sidenote{one}\sidenote{two}

2 Text\sidenote{one}\margincite{two}

3 Text\sidenote{one}\sidenotemark

4 Text\sidenotemark text\sidenotetext{one}\sidenotemark

\end{document}
```

However, the solution is borrowed from the `footmisc` package and some people might call it a hack. It becomes obvious when looking at the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
Text\footnotemark text\footnotetext{one}\footnotemark
\end{document}
```

Which leads to

[image: footmisc]

My previous solution was based on `\ifnextchar\sidenote` constructions, which were described by Clemens Niederberger

*I didn’t like some smaller things (not bugs) done by the sidenotes
package such as inserting kerns and superscripted commas for multiple marks.
I prefer to let my fnpct9 package handle these things*

This made me review my options. Also, `\ifnextchar` has to be inserted in every macro that is added such as `\margincite` and it does not allow user defined macros including the sidenote ones.

`fnpct` has a solution by allowing several arguments: `\sidenote{aaa;bbb}` would print two notes. It does not work (well) if references are put in the game.

```
\sidenote{aaa;\fullcite{citekey};ccc}
```

does not seem right from a user perspective.

Is any of the three solutions preferred? Is there another way to reliably detect subsequent macros?

Comment: why does `\sidenotetext` (or `\footnotetext` in footmisc) have a `\marker` ? surely you only want the marker at points where you have added a superscript?

Comment: because otherwise `\sidenote\sidenote` will not work, because it becomes `\sidenotemark\sidenotetext\sidenotemark` and the sidenotemarks are not subsequent any more.

Comment: well that's a bug:-)  The marker should only be placed if the superscript is already positioned, even if that means \sidenote and \sidenotetext not sharing so much code

Comment: `footmisc` is 19 years old. I felt, there is no better solution if not added, yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spurious comma in the last case is because you used a `\marker` in the "text" command that had not set a superscript mark, insterad it should be at the end of `\sidenote(mark)`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\providecommand*{\multiplefootnotemarker}{3sp}

\NewDocumentCommand \marker { } {%
\kern-\multiplefootnotemarker%
\kern\multiplefootnotemarker\relax%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \checker { } {%
\ifdim\lastkern=\multiplefootnotemarker\relax%
      \textsuperscript{,}%
\fi%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \fullcite { m } {%
#1%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \margincite { m } {%
\sidenote{\fullcite{#1}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \sidenote { m } {%
\sidenotemark%
\sidenotetext{#1}%
\marker%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \sidenotemark { } {%
\checker%
\textsuperscript{1}%
\marker%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { m } {%
\marginpar{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
1 Text\sidenote{one}\sidenote{two}

2 Text\sidenote{one}\margincite{two}

3 Text\sidenote{one}\sidenotemark

4 Text\sidenotemark text\sidenotetext{one}\sidenotemark

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is amazing, it did not get that idea by myself... Would you also say, that this is the preferred way to go, compared to the two other ideas (one macro with several arguments or `\ifnextchar`)?

Comment: @Andy the various techniques have pros and cons using a marker in the horizontal list is probably easier to control than looking ahead as that has problems with things being hidden by expansion etc.